# Why is it called a Lognormal distribution instead of an Expnormal distribution?

Tags: logarithms, terminology, normal-distribution, intuition, math-history

$$
e^Z \sim \mathrm{Lognormal} \iff Z \sim \mathrm{Normal}
$$

Why would we call the exponential of a normal distribution log-normal?  The fact that the log of a lognormal is normal seems bizarre.  It would make more sense if the log of an expnormal was normal or the exp of a lognormal was normal.

I am thinking about as Log(Normal), but that gives the opposite of the correct intuition, so what is the correct way to think about it?  "The **Log** of this is **Normal**"?  Is there any history or analogous terminology that can guide me to the right intuition here?

Comment: Perhaps they were thinking 'this is normal when plotted on a log scale'.

Comment: This is frustratingly unanswered (and unquestioned!) in my limited research. My interpretation is that it's read as Log[of this variable is]Normal. But it's quite unintuitive, given how most of us think about functions of random variables.