# What's the opposite of a lognormal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, logarithms, normal-distribution

If $Y$ is normally distributed, and $X = \exp{(Y)}$ then $X$ has a log-normal distribution.  I'm curious about the opposite case. If the pdf of $Y$ is a half-normal distribution (normally distributed over the positive domain and zero over the negative domain) and $X = \log_{10}{(Y)}$ what is the resulting distribution in $X$? Does this "exp-normal"  distribution have a closed-form PDF or any known properties?

I've found a few questions on this site already that are similar to this question ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268139/why-is-it-called-a-lognormal-distribution-instead-of-an-expnormal-distribution)), but nothing that explicitly answers my question.

Comment: You do not want to take logarithms of negative numbers.  Normal distributions have support on the real number line

Comment: This is extremely compelling, I didn't think about that!